# How to set "web application properties" so HSQLDB can use them?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, hsqldb

I want to use HSQLdb for my Spring-based web application, and I want to have the data persistent (so in-memory is out).  According to the [hsqldb documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_variables_url), I can use variables in the connection URL - but the document doesn't say how to set these.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289245/relative-path-to-hsqldb-files-in-a-web-app-doesnt-work), and there are some interesting tactics, such as creating a listener to set properties when the context loads.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160343/where-should-a-java-web-application-store-its-data) explains how to get an appropriate location, so I've combined the two approaches.  I've tried using a listener to set a new property with the path lifted from `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` (it's a `File`), I've tried using that property directly.  Neither approach works.

[One punter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11290019/747739) has commented that one could set `user.home` via a listener, then use `~` in the HSQLdb URL.  I've not tried this, but even if it does work, it strikes me as a little yuck, as I redefine something I potentially don't want to.  I'm looking for the "proper" way.  How do I set that which the HSQLdb calls "web application properties"? (Or is there one that would be suitable?)

From the documentation:

> If the database URL contains a string in the form of `${propname}`
>   then the sequence of characters is replaced with the system property
>   with the given name. For example you can use this in the URL of a
>   database that is used in a web application and define the system
>   property, `"propname"` in the web application properties. In the example
>   below, the string `${mydbpath}` is replaced with the value of the
>   property, `mydbpath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the source code, `System.setProperty(key, value)`

Kicking myself - my issue was first an ancient version of HSQLdb then it wasn't unloading - a restart of Tomcat, and everything started working.